# IronPython and xml.etree.ElementTree illegal characters error

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, ironpython, elementtree

I'm trying to read an XML file which contains utf8 character using xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(). When running the code using the regular python (2.7.4) interpreter, it works fine and I get no errors, but when I try to run the same code using IronPython, I get an `Syntax error at line 18: illegal character in content` error. I have also tried opening the file first using *codecs.open("file.xml", "r", "utf-8")*, but received the following error `Illegal characters in path`

How can I fix this error in IronPython? Using alternative xml parsers is possible, but I prefer solving the problem in xml.etree.ElementTree. Thanks.

Comment: "Illegal characters in path" sounds like it's complaining about the pathname, not the contents. Is your pathname really just `"file.xml"`, or is it something that may have non-ASCII characters in it?

Comment: As I wrote, the file contains utf8 characters in it. Also, the illegal characters in path regards the file, not the pathname. I have updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Again, unless there's something very wrong, "illegal characters in path" should _not_ refer to the contents, but to the pathname. Most commonly this is caused by people using Windows pathnames with unescaped backslashes in non-raw strings (e.g., `"foo\bar\file.xml"` has a backspace character in the middle of it). I suspect that using `codecs.open` (or `io.open`) actually is the right solution here, but a different problem (with your pathname) is preventing you from getting far enough to see that.

Comment: I'm using an escaped pathname, `C:\\Users\\username\\Music\\iTunes\\iTunes Music Library.xml`. The characters that are causing the problem are 강남스타일. Once again, this works find in the regular python interpreter, but not in IronPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by "reinstalling" the ElementTree module. Downloaded it from over [here](http://effbot.org/downloads#elementtree), and installed it by copying the source to *..\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\*.

Comment: That's generally a very bad way to install things. Some packages will work fine; others will work but with bugs or limitations or missed optimizations; others won't work at all. You should always run `ipy64 setup.py install` from within the directory, or use some tool that does the equivalent for you (`pip`, your favorite IDE, etc.).